# Run time call within pprint

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, pprint

How to pass value inside pprint at run time?

```
import nltk, sys
from pprint import pprint
from nltk.corpus import framenet as fn
#Word = raw_input("enter a word: ")
pprint(fn.frames(r'(?i)Medical_specialties'))
f = fn.frame(256)
f.ID
f.name
f.definition
print f
print '\b'
pprint(sorted([x for x in f.FE]))
pprint(f.frameRelations)
print
```

At run time, I need to get a word from the user and pass it to fn.frames function in place of Medical_specialties, which in turn throws a list of frames as frame ID relevant to the word. Then I can call those numbers to query further.

Output:

```
[<frame ID=256 name=Medical_specialties>]
```

Comment: how has this got to do with `nltk` ;P ?

Comment: It is framenet corpus for nltk,
from nltk.corpus import framenet as fn

Comment: Please show the whole code or at least a minimal working example so that we can help you better.

Comment: Elaborated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Although you happen to be working with the `nltk`, your question has nothing to do with it (or with `pprint`, for that matter): You need to input a string from the user, then stick `"(?i)"` in front to construct your desired regexp.

Since that's all you need to do, the simplest solution is this:

```
word = raw_input("enter a word: ")
rexp = "(?i)" + word
pprint(fn.frames(rexp))
```

A more powerful way to put together strings is with python's [C-style string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting), or the newer [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) syntax. E.g., to specify word boundaries before and after the input "word", you'd do it like this (C-style syntax):

```
rexp = r"(?i)\b%s\b" % word
```

You'll probably find the above links hard to digest, so try [this exposition](https://pyformat.info/) or [this high-voted SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.